# UWP app service does not reconnect with fulltrust process

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I have an an UWP application with a full trust windows form process acting as systray icon. The two components can communicate efficiently after UWP cold launch. If I terminate the UWP app and relaunch it, leaving the systray component up the UWP application stops sending messages. While the systray can still talk to the UWP component.

What am I doing wrong?

### UWP App.xaml.cs

```cs
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public static AppServiceConnection Connection = null;
        public static BackgroundTaskDeferral AppServiceDeferral = null;

        protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
            if (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails is AppServiceTriggerDetails details)
            {
                if (details.CallerPackageFamilyName == Package.Current.Id.FamilyName)
                {
                    AppServiceDeferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
                    args.TaskInstance.Canceled += Connection_OnTaskCanceled;
                    Connection = details.AppServiceConnection;
                    Connection.RequestReceived += Connection_OnRequestReceived;
                    Connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;
                    AppServiceConnected?.Invoke(this, args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Connection_ServiceClosed(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceClosedEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("service closed");
            Connection.ServiceClosed -= Connection_ServiceClosed;
            Connection = null;
        }

        private void Connection_OnTaskCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            if (AppServiceDeferral != null)
            {
                AppServiceDeferral.Complete();
            }
            AppServiceDisconnected?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

### SYSTRAY connect method

```cs
        private async Task App_Connect()
        {
            if (!Standalone)
            {
                if (connection == null)
                {
                    connection = new AppServiceConnection();
                    connection.PackageFamilyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
                    connection.AppServiceName = "AppServiceName";
                    connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;
                    AppServiceConnectionStatus connectionStatus = await connection.OpenAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Application Package Project to package the UWP app and Winform together?

Comment: I am packaging all using appcenter.ms

Comment: Could you please try to package your project in Visual Studio using Windows Application Package Project?